# Why the tooltip not init with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to add a tooltip using jQuery but I can´t find where is the error

**JS:**

```
$(document).on("ready",function (){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<p>
  <i class="fa fa-user font-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="news"></i> 5  |
  <i class="fa fa-user font-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="enable"></i> 5  |
  <i class="fa fa-user font-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="disable"></i> 5
</p>
```

Comment: Code is okay. You have something else you don't show here.

Comment: [The documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) says that `.on("ready"` works differently than the other versions. Have you tried the other versions?

Comment: Show the HTML that adds jQuery and Bootstrap scripts.

Comment: One possibility is that the tooltip off of the page--is the HTML that you have there at the very top?  If so, there is no room for the tooltip at the top, which is where you have specified it to be placed by `data-placement="top"`

Comment: was the space in top thank you Guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included the jquery-ui.css and jquery-ui.js file?
Try to create a new html file and type this, and see the result :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Tooltip - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $( document ).tooltip();
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    label {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 5em;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a href="#" title="That&apos;s what this widget is">Tooltips</a> can be attached to any element. When you hover
    the element with your mouse, the title attribute is displayed in a little box next to the element, just like a native tooltip.</p>
    <p>But as it's not a native tooltip, it can be styled. Any themes built with
    <a href="http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/" title="ThemeRoller: jQuery UI&apos;s theme builder application">ThemeRoller</a>
    will also style tooltips accordingly.</p>
    <p>Tooltips are also useful for form elements, to show some additional information in the context of each field.</p>
    <p><label for="age">Your age:</label><input id="age" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes."></p>
    <p>Hover the field to see the tooltip.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```